# Solr, sort same weigthing results alphebetically

Tags: apache-2.2, drupal, solr

I'm working in a project that uses Drupal Solr module and I'm facing a problem plus I'm a complete rookie on Solr config.

The issue is that same weigthing results does not appear ordered alphabetically.

Is that possible? What sould I configure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change the field type of the field you are sorting from `text` to `string`; that should do the trick.